# Connecting to MS Dynamics AX using Component Object Model in Python

Tags: python, com, axapta, win32com

I'm new in COM programming with Python and in MS Dynamics AX. Is there a way to connect MS Dynamics AX using Python? I would like to use win32com to connect Axapta and get/write some data. I found that there is COM Business Connector for this, but I can't find any documentation or examples how to use it. There is a lot of examples how to do this with MS Excel (I mean get data from Excel using COM in Python).

Could you give me any examples or tutorials how to do this? I found only examples for .Net Business Connector.

Comment: Which version of Dynamics AX are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009

Answer (score 0):

Business Connector is .NET in the first place (and marked as [`COM visible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute)).

Phyton example:

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet')
from Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet import Axapta
my_instance = Axapta()
my_instance.Logon...
```

See more at [How to: Read Data Using .NET Business Connector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197126.aspx).

Comment: It looks good, but it gives me an error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet'`. I tried also `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('path\to\'Microsoft.Dynamics.B‌​usinessConnectorNet.‌​dll)`, - there was error too: `AttributeError: AddReferenceToFileAndPath` - and `sys.path.append(r"C:\path") clr.AddReference("MSConnectorNet.dll")` - still not working. I tried both x86 and x86-64 Python versions with Pythonnet (installed via PIP). I can import something from standard library (e.g. System). Path to BusinessConnector is in system PATH.